# Compare two growth curves in R

Tags: r

I am trying to compare statistically the growth curves from two different populations of animals. I have different dates for its datapoint for each individual, as well as a different number of datapoints per individual. So, all the dates are different, and in some cases, I just have one datapoint per subject.

I will need to compare two non-linear mixed-effects models. Could anyone suggest to me how to do that?

My columns are just three: Subject, Date and Weight.

Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As a start point for plotting the graphs I suggest looking in to the ggplot2 package, it has a wide range of functionality and should be able to produce the graphs you want. You can group by subject and population. To solve the date issue I suggest using the  lubridate package and plotting the time since first measurement rather than date on the x axis.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I can plot the data, but what I am looking for is to test the difference between the curves statistically.

Comment: Do you know what specific tests you want to do?

Comment: If the data was linear I would do a mixed-effects model with the lme package like: Weight ~ Age * Population, random=~ 1|Subject. I would like to see if there is any effect in weight due to the population. But since the data is not linear, I am unsure.

Comment: Ok, this is more of a stats question than an r question then. If you have a model for the population you could see how well that model fits the data, but other than that I'd suggest looking at information on statistics, or looking at some papers in your field to see what they do to figure out what you want to do, then come back here once you have a plan and want to implement it.